# How to check other EA is running in MQL4?

Tags: mql4

As title, is this possible to check other EA is running or not? 
For example, my EA would like to check whether other EA is running or not? Or the EA don't know this information? Thanks.

Comment: Use a general error handler to find the return code, when the EA is blocked, due to another EA already running.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no official way to find out if another Expert Advisor is running.

If you are writing your EAs yourself, you could put such an information into the [global variables](https://docs.mql4.com/globals).